# Topics not getting a chance to reach users who could answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, off-topic, cross-posting

I think it is very frustrating and hurts the sites "usefulness" that people are so prompt at closing topics they don't really understand.

It would be nice solutions were found avoid theses cases:

- Legitimate cross-domain questions
  The question can be related to domain A and B.
  On A.stackexchange.com, people say it's off-topic and you should ask B.stackexchange.com.
  On B.stackexchange.com, people say it's off-topic and you should ask A.stackexchange.com.

Real example: Ask a question about photography software. "Software" will say that only photographers use that specific software so you should ask "Photography". "Photography" will say that only software geeks know how to use software so you should ask "Software".

I think if it is a legitimate cross-domain question, the same question should be able to appear in both sites without cross-posting. By the way this should required some validation. I know, that's not a small feature change.

- Sub-domain topics
  The question is about topic X in domain A.
  People who know a lot about domain A but don't know topic X will downvote the question or tag it as off-topic.

Those happen even if the [domain].stackexchange.com site has a dedicated tag for topic X.

As a result, specific questions tend to get closed by users who don't know the topic and therefore are not given a chance a to reach the small fraction of user who could answer them.

Or maybe I missed something?

Comment: If both sites want to close your question, you simply haven't done enough to make it clearly on-topic for the site you're on. And as always, don't ask cross-domain questions. In the rare case a question is on-topic for multiple sites, pick one and stick to it.

Comment: I know this, theorecally. But when you apply it, it doesn't work. You stick to a site, you're sent to the other, then they send you back or someone say it's cross-posting. Cross-domain questions exist, so having "don't ask cross-domain questions" looks like a hugh weakness.

Comment: No, you won't be sent back and forth. If that does happen you have not asked an appropriate question for your first site,  nor for the second. And you may run into users who don't know what's on-topic for the site they point you at. Cross-domain questions may exist, but not the kind that should have the outcome you bring forth. If that exact scenario happened to you, please show us. Because I'd suspect there is another underlying problem than the one you're trying to solve.

Comment: It happened here: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24510/how-can-i-correctly-decode-cpr-positions-from-ads-b-frames   The topic was put on hold , then released. And some user commented "I think some people are unfamiliar with ADS-B and didn't realize that your question had to do with transponder signal coding." I may have another example, if I find it back.

Comment: I don't find the other but I was asking a question about Adobe Lightroom (which is a photography developement software) in the photography site. Users were debating in comments wheter asking a question about Lightroom was photography or software, and they couldn't get a clear answer. I think I asked to one of th software sites too, but they said only photographers might have experience with Lightroom.

Comment: Yet, this happened on sites that has a specific tag ready for the topic.

Comment: ... the history of that question only shows you deleted and undeleting it? I don't see evidence of it being put on hold at any point. Maybe I'm missing something? As to the debate around on-topic-ness, that should then simply be taken to a site's meta to establish a clear-cut answer.

Answer (score 5):

First, closing is not permanent. It can be reversed. You mention this in one of your comments. One of the common ways questions are re-opened is when people who understand them and could answer them vote to reopen.

Second, if a question seems to fall between two sites, the asker must do the extra work to make sure it is seen to be on topic. The definition of on topic serves no good purpose if we relax it because a nice person really wants to know something. That means you may need to explain acronyms, for example. If your question makes sense only to a narrow subset of the sites users, the other users may think it is off topic, so take the time to explain it fully. (Consider also including a sentence about why you don't think it belongs on the other site.)

I see many questions on Travel that have to do with hiking or backpacking, and many questions on The Great Outdoors that have to do with traveling to a location for outdoor activities. It's possible some of these questions might have been on topic on either or both sites. But they aren't closed, they are dealt with on the site. That's because they were written in a way that makes them on topic. It can be done.

To learn more about how to write a question so it's more clearly on topic, your best bet is the per-site meta. On all the sites I frequent, at any time the meta front page has at least two "why is this question on topic" or "why is this question off topic" questions with detailed scope discussions. In many cases the meta folks help the post get edited into something on topic that gets re-opened. Learn to use the amazing resource that is the per site meta, and you'll get your answers. Come to the site wide meta to suggest a rule or culture change that prevents people from voting to close if you think it's unfair, and you'll get nowhere. (Well, you got this answer, which I hope was useful.)

Comment: Thank you. There some useful info. Just: "narrow subset ... explain it fully". Isn't it the role of the appropriate tag to place the question in its context. "Consider also including ... why you don't think it belongs on the other site." Already tried, usually makes it worse.

Comment: Never rely on the tag to provide **all** the context. A few moments spent expanding acronyms the first time is, like showing what you've tried and including all the information you have the first time, often the key to a question staying open. But for more specific advice, go to the per-site meta, because every site is a little different and I don't know every site's norms.